# Open "Find shelvesets" page for specified user

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-extensions

I'm trying to develop a Visual Studio 2013 Team Foundation Server extension.

I want to open the "Find shelvesets" page for a certain user, but I can't find a way to do so.

I'm trying to use the following piece of code:

```
ITeamExplorer teamExplorer = (ITeamExplorer)ServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(ITeamExplorer));
if (teamExplorer != null)
{
    teamExplorer.NavigateToPage(new Guid(TeamExplorerPageIds.FindShelvesets), null);
}
```

This opens the FindShelvesets page but it shows the shelvesets of the current user. I want it to show the shelvesets of another user which I can pass via a parameter.

The NavigateToPage method accepts a GUID parameter that specifies the page that will be opened and it also takes a context parameter which is the context for that page.

I assume that I can pass an object as the second parameter that can override the default user for the FindShelvesets page. The problem is I don't know what that object should be, and I wasn't able to find any documentation that can help me. I tried passing a string containing the name of another user, but that didn't work.

So the question is, how can I navigate to the FindShelvesets page for an arbitrary user. Also, where can I find some documentation as to what contexts the different Team Explorer pages can accept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When digging into the '*Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Controls*' assembly, particularly the '*Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Controls.FindShelvesets.FindShelvesetsPage.InitializeModel(PageInitializeEventArgs e)*' method, you'll see that they use an internal class named '*FindShelvesetsModelContext*' as context / parameter (see [my blog post about this one and others](http://blog.joergbattermann.com/2016/04/23/navigating-to-team-explorer-pages-and-passing-along-context-and-parameters/)) .. and because it's internal, you cannot really provide it 'from the outside' unless you use Reflection - which might be your only option if absolutely required.. but obviously a quite hideous and unstable/unreliable one.